# understanding the output of Sagemaker Object Detection prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, amazon-sagemaker

I need help understanding the output of the Amazon Sagemaker object-detection algorithm.

Here's my underlying goal: identify when a ping pong ball is in play and mark it's location in an image frame.

Sample images from a video feed:

[image: No ball in play]
[image]

Steps so far: 
1. I've taken n-video frames from a ping pong match.

2. I used RectLabel to hand annotate the location of the ping pong ball.
3. Using RectLabel, I converted those labels into a JSON file. Example here:

```py
{"images":[
    {"id":1,"file_name":"thumb0462.png","width":0,"height":0},
    {"id":2,"file_name":"thumb0463.png","width":0,"height":0},
    {"id":3,"file_name":"thumb0464.png","width":0,"height":0},
    ...
    {"id":4582,"file_name":"thumb6492.png","width":0,"height":0}],
"annotations":[
    {"area":198,"iscrowd":0,"id":1,"image_id":5,"category_id":1,"segmentation":[[59,152,76,152,76,142,59,142]],"bbox":[59,142,18,11]},
    {"area":221,"iscrowd":0,"id":2,"image_id":6,"category_id":1,"segmentation":[[83,155,99,155,99,143,83,143]],"bbox":[83,143,17,13]},
    {"area":399,"iscrowd":0,"id":3,"image_id":8,"category_id":1,"segmentation":[[118,144,136,144,136,124,118,124]],"bbox":[118,124,19,21]},
    {"area":361,"iscrowd":0,"id":4,"image_id":9,"category_id":1,"segmentation":[[132,123,150,123,150,105,132,105]],"bbox":[132,105,19,19]},
    ...
"categories":[{"name":"pp_ball","id":1}]
}
```

4. I used a function to separate the annotations into train and validate folders, as expected by SageMaker's input channels.

```py
file_name = './pp-ball-annotations.json'
with open(file_name) as f:
    js = json.load(f)
    images = js['images']
    categories = js['categories']
    annotations = js['annotations']
    for i in images:
        jsonFile = i['file_name']
        jsonFile = jsonFile.split('.')[0] + '.json'

        line = {}
        line['file'] = i['file_name']
        line['image_size'] = [{
            'width': int(i['width']),
            'height': int(i['height']),
            'depth': 3
        }]
        line['annotations'] = []
        line['categories'] = []
        for j in annotations:
            if j['image_id'] == i['id'] and len(j['bbox']) > 0:
                line['annotations'].append({
                    'class_id': int(j['category_id']),
                    'top': int(j['bbox'][1]),
                    'left': int(j['bbox'][0]),
                    'width': int(j['bbox'][2]),
                    'height': int(j['bbox'][3])
                })
                class_name = ''
                for k in categories:
                    if int(j['category_id']) == k['id']:
                        class_name = str(k['name'])
                assert class_name is not ''
                line['categories'].append({
                    'class_id': int(j['category_id']),
                    'name': class_name
                })
        if line['annotations']:
            with open(os.path.join('generated', jsonFile), 'w') as p:
                json.dump(line, p)

jsons = os.listdir('generated')
print ('There are {} images that have annotation files'.format(len(jsons)))
```

5. I moved the files into an Amazon S3 bucket with four channels (folders) as required by SageMaker: /train, /validation, /train_annotation, and /validation_annotation.

```py
num_annotated_files = len(jsons)
train_split_pct = 0.70
num_train_jsons = int(num_annotated_files * train_split_pct)
random.shuffle(jsons) # randomize/shuffle the JSONs to reduce reliance on *sequenced* frames
train_jsons = jsons[:num_train_jsons]
val_jsons = jsons[num_train_jsons:]

#Moving training files to the training folders
for i in train_jsons:
    image_file = './images/'+i.split('.')[0]+'.png'
    shutil.move(image_file, './train/')
    shutil.move('./generated/'+i, './train_annotation/')

#Moving validation files to the validation folders
for i in val_jsons:
    image_file = './images/'+i.split('.')[0]+'.png'
    shutil.move(image_file, './validation/')
    shutil.move('./generated/'+i, './validation_annotation/')


### Upload to S3
import sagemaker
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
sess = sagemaker.Session()

from sagemaker.amazon.amazon_estimator import get_image_uri
training_image = get_image_uri(sess.boto_region_name, 'object-detection', repo_version="latest")

bucket = 'pp-balls-object-detection' # custom bucket name.
# bucket = sess.default_bucket()
prefix = 'rect-label-test'

train_channel = prefix + '/train'
validation_channel = prefix + '/validation'
train_annotation_channel = prefix + '/train_annotation'
validation_annotation_channel = prefix + '/validation_annotation'

sess.upload_data(path='train', bucket=bucket, key_prefix=train_channel)
sess.upload_data(path='validation', bucket=bucket, key_prefix=validation_channel)
sess.upload_data(path='train_annotation', bucket=bucket, key_prefix=train_annotation_channel)
sess.upload_data(path='validation_annotation', bucket=bucket, key_prefix=validation_annotation_channel)

s3_train_data = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, train_channel)
s3_validation_data = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, validation_channel)
s3_train_annotation = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, train_annotation_channel)
s3_validation_annotation = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, validation_annotation_channel)
```

6. Created a SageMaker object detector with certain hyperparameters. I note that these hyperparameters are 'unusual' given other examples I've seen: num_classes = 1, use_pretrained_model=0, and image_shape = 438.

```py
s3_output_location = 's3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix)

od_model = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(training_image,
                                         role,
                                         train_instance_count=1,
                                         train_instance_type='ml.p3.2xlarge',
                                         train_volume_size = 50,
                                         train_max_run = 360000,
                                         input_mode = 'File',
                                         output_path=s3_output_location,
                                         sagemaker_session=sess)

od_model.set_hyperparameters(base_network='resnet-50',
                             use_pretrained_model=0,
                             num_classes=1,
                             mini_batch_size=15,
                             epochs=30,
                             learning_rate=0.001,
                             lr_scheduler_step='10',
                             lr_scheduler_factor=0.1,
                             optimizer='sgd',
                             momentum=0.9,
                             weight_decay=0.0005,
                             overlap_threshold=0.5,
                             nms_threshold=0.45,
                             image_shape=438,
                             label_width=600,
                             num_training_samples=num_train_jsons)
```

7. I set the train/validate location for the object-detector, called the .fit function, and deployed the model to an endpoint:

```py
train_data = sagemaker.session.s3_input(s3_train_data, distribution='FullyReplicated',
                        content_type='image/png', s3_data_type='S3Prefix')
validation_data = sagemaker.session.s3_input(s3_validation_data, distribution='FullyReplicated',
                             content_type='image/png', s3_data_type='S3Prefix')
train_annotation = sagemaker.session.s3_input(s3_train_annotation, distribution='FullyReplicated',
                             content_type='image/png', s3_data_type='S3Prefix')
validation_annotation = sagemaker.session.s3_input(s3_validation_annotation, distribution='FullyReplicated',
                             content_type='image/png', s3_data_type='S3Prefix')

data_channels = {'train': train_data, 'validation': validation_data,
                 'train_annotation': train_annotation, 'validation_annotation':validation_annotation}

od_model.fit(inputs=data_channels, logs=True)

object_detector = od_model.deploy(initial_instance_count = 1,
                             instance_type = 'ml.m4.xlarge')
```

8. I invoke the endpoint by passing it a PNG file in bytes:

```py
file_with_path = 'test/thumb0695.png'
with open(file_with_path, 'rb') as image:
            f = image.read()
            b = bytearray(f)
            ne = open('n.txt', 'wb')
            ne.write(b)

        results = object_detector.predict(b)
        detections = json.loads(results)
        print(detections)
```

9. The AWS Sagemaker documentation says to expect the output in the following format:

> Each row in this .json file contains an array that represents a detected object. Each of these object arrays consists of a list of six numbers. The first number is the predicted class label. The second number is the associated confidence score for the detection. The last four numbers represent the bounding box coordinates [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]. These output bounding box corner indices are normalized by the overall image size. Note that this encoding is different than that use by the input .json format. For example, in the first entry of the detection result, 0.3088374733924866 is the left coordinate (x-coordinate of upper-left corner) of the bounding box as a ratio of the overall image width, 0.07030484080314636 is the top coordinate (y-coordinate of upper-left corner) of the bounding box as a ratio of the overall image height, 0.7110607028007507 is the right coordinate (x-coordinate of lower-right corner) of the bounding box as a ratio of the overall image width, and 0.9345266819000244 is the bottom coordinate (y-coordinate of lower-right corner) of the bounding box as a ratio of the overall image height.

Let's look at a test image:

> {"id":9,"file_name":"thumb0470.png","width":438,"height":240}

[image: test image thumb0470]

which has a ball with this bounding box [132,105,19,19] (read as x-top-left, y-top-left, box-width, box-height).

Given that my object-detector was trained to detect ONE class (num_classes=1), I expected this kind of output for this image:

> {'prediction': [[1.0, 0.71, 0.55, 0.239, 0.629, 0.283]]}

Instead, I get this output:

```py
{'prediction': [[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]]}
```

**So now the question**:  why is this model giving me 400 JSON elements, instead of just one?

My current hypothesis:  this object detection model is so weakly trained (very possible, as this was just a first pass with too few images), that the Single Shot Detector is identifying what it thinks to be 400 instances of the "ping pong ball" in the image.

But even if my hypothesis is correct, why is the output repeated so much?  There are 178 identical 'predictions' of the form

> [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]

which if interpreted, means:

0.0 - class object "0" which I did not define. So I assume this means "no ball in play"

1.0 - 100% confidence

0.0 - the xmin position as a ratio of width = 0

0.0 - the ymin position as a ratio of height = 0

1.0 - the xmax position as a ratio of width = 240

0.0 - the ymax position as a ratio of height = 0

The coordinates [xmin: 0, ymin: 0, xmax: 240, ymax: 0] is like drawing a line across the first pixel.

[image: prediction visualized using matplotlib]

Thanks for your help!

-------  EDIT based on Ryo's answer ------

Re-mapping the category ID to index-base 0 worked like a charm.  Here are the results from just 2,000 labeled images:

[image: ping pong ball detected 1]
[image: ping pong ball detected 2]

Here's the code after Ryo's helpful answer:

```
def fixCategoryId(category_id):
    return category_id - 1;

with open(file_name) as f:
    js = json.load(f)
    images = js['images']
    categories = js['categories']
    annotations = js['annotations']
    for i in images:
        jsonFile = i['file_name']
        jsonFile = jsonFile.split('.')[0] + '.json'

        line = {}
        line['file'] = i['file_name']
        line['image_size'] = [{
            'width': int(i['width']),
            'height': int(i['height']),
            'depth': 3
        }]
        line['annotations'] = []
        line['categories'] = []
        for j in annotations:
            if j['image_id'] == i['id'] and len(j['bbox']) > 0:
                line['annotations'].append({
                    'class_id': fixCategoryId(int(j['category_id'])),
                    'top': int(j['bbox'][1]),
                    'left': int(j['bbox'][0]),
                    'width': int(j['bbox'][2]),
                    'height': int(j['bbox'][3])
                })
                class_name = ''
                for k in categories:
                    if int(j['category_id']) == k['id']:
                        class_name = str(k['name'])
                assert class_name is not ''
                line['categories'].append({
                    'class_id': fixCategoryId(int(j['category_id'])),
                    'name': class_name
                })
        if line['annotations']:
            with open(os.path.join('generated', jsonFile), 'w') as p:
                json.dump(line, p)

jsons = os.listdir('generated')
print ('There are {} images that have annotation files'.format(len(jsons)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though 'category_id' in the COCO JSON file starts from 1, 'class_id' in the Amazon SageMaker JSON file starts from 0.

Your conversion code should be like this.

```
def fixCategoryId(category_id):
    return category_id - 1;

with open(coco_json_path) as f:
    js = json.load(f)
    images = js['images']
    categories = js['categories']
    annotations = js['annotations']
    for i in images:
        jsonFile = i['file_name']
        jsonFile = jsonFile.split('.')[0] + '.json'

        line = {}
        line['file'] = i['file_name']
        line['image_size'] = [{
            'width': int(i['width']),
            'height': int(i['height']),
            'depth': 3
        }]
        line['annotations'] = []
        line['categories'] = []
        for j in annotations:
            if j['image_id'] == i['id'] and len(j['bbox']) > 0:
                line['annotations'].append({
                    'class_id': fixCategoryId(int(j['category_id'])),
                    'top': int(j['bbox'][1]),
                    'left': int(j['bbox'][0]),
                    'width': int(j['bbox'][2]),
                    'height': int(j['bbox'][3])
                })
                class_name = ''
                for k in categories:
                    if int(j['category_id']) == k['id']:
                        class_name = str(k['name'])
                assert class_name is not ''
                line['categories'].append({
                    'class_id': fixCategoryId(int(j['category_id'])),
                    'name': class_name
                })
        if line['annotations']:
            with open(os.path.join(sagemaker_json_path, jsonFile), 'w') as p:
                json.dump(line, p)
```

[In the Amazon SageMaker doc](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/object_detection_pascalvoc_coco/object_detection_image_json_format.ipynb), they are doing this using get_coco_mapper().

```
import json
import logging

def get_coco_mapper():
    original_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
                    21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
                    41, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
                    61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 70, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
                    81, 82, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
    iter_counter = 0
    COCO = {}
    for orig in original_list:
        COCO[orig] = iter_counter
        iter_counter += 1
    return COCO
```

After you trained the model, you have to check whether each loss has decreased or not.

```
od_model.fit(inputs=data_channels, logs=True)

[11/04/2019 09:26:46 INFO 140651482974016] #quality_metric: host=algo-1, epoch=499, batch=11 train cross_entropy <loss>=(0.20304460724736212)
[11/04/2019 09:26:46 INFO 140651482974016] #quality_metric: host=algo-1, epoch=499, batch=11 train smooth_l1 <loss>=(0.06970448779799958)
```

If you have some questions, let us know.

Comment: Excellent observation and many thanks for the code snippet @RyoKawamura.  Worked like a charm :)  I'll add the results from 2,000 labeled images

Answer (score 0):

From: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/algo-object-detection-tech-notes.html

> Object detection algorithm identifies and locates all instances of
>   objects in an image from a known collection of object categories

This explains why you are getting back 400 items in your response array from predict.

The output data here is erroneous. You have it mapped correctly at the top of the image, but its height is 0, so it's essentially nowhere.

From: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/object-detection.html#object-detection-inputoutput

> The "categories" property stores the mapping between the class index
>   and class name. The class indices should be numbered successively and
>   the numbering should start with 0. The "categories" property is
>   optional for the annotation .json file

Your categories array starts with class id 1.

You have provided the sample json you got from the labelling tool, but there is no sample of the json you have produced in file `generated`. It would be helpful to see sample of that output as well.